# Term for generating set of a G-set

Tags: group-theory, terminology

Given a group $G$ and a $G$-set $X$, I want to say that a subset $E \subseteq X$ has the property
$$
X = \{ g \cdot x \; ; \; g \in G, x \in E \}
$$
Is there an “official” word for this? e.g. $E$ is a $G$-generating set of $X$?

Comment: You want a set that intersects each orbit? Possibly a set of representatives for the orbits?

Comment: $E$ should be allowed to contain more than one representative of an orbit, which is not the case for a set of representatives.

Comment: Then just a set that intersects each orbit. I don't think that has a nice name.

Comment: You could say that $E$ contains a *fundamental domain*. A fundamental domain is a set containing exactly one representative from each orbit, although usually this term is used only when you have a topological group acting continuously on a topological space. A reader who knew what the term meant would also know to give all sets involved discrete topologies, so I think it can be used in this case. You could also write your situation compactly as $G\cdot E=X$.